# What does "turned the schooner end-for-end" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> > 'Who do these things?' Dan asked, and straightened his back at the bench as he turned the schooner end-for-end in the vice to get at her
> >     counter.
> >
> > 'Them which don't wish other men to work no better nor quicker than they do,' growled Mr Springett. 'Don't pinch her so hard in the vice,
> >     Mus' Dan. Put a piece o' rag in the jaws, or you'll bruise her.

This from "[Rewards and Fairies](http://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/rg_wrongthing1.htm)" by Kipling.

I do not understand what the  line  below means.

> and straightened his back at the bench as he turned the schooner end-for-end in the vice to get at her counter.

1. What does "turned the schooner end-for-end" mean?
2. What does "to get at her counter" mean? Is there any counter on the schooner?

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? Do you know what the words mean? Which words are confusing you?

Comment: Please use your dictionary! See #34 at this [link](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/end?s=t) at Dictionary.com.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!

as he turned the schooner end-for-end in the vice to get at her counter.

1 What does "turned the schooner end-for-end" mean?

2 What does "to get at her counter" mean?
 Is thre any counter on the schooner?

I am glad if can have any suggestion.

Comment: “turn end for end” means to turn 180 degrees-literally put the front end where the back end was and vice versa. The *counter* or *counter deck* is part of the stern of some boats.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to include a link to the story? That way we can look at the context more without having to search for the text...

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice. They are so helpful!

Comment: *He turned the schooner around*. How? *End-for-end*. So he turned it 180 degrees. as@Jim said. In other words, he turned it so that where the bow had been, the stern now was, and where the stern had been, the bow now was. He switched the schooner's position in the vice, so that the ends of the schooner were now on opposite sides.

Comment: Your link does not go to the story. Try [this one](https://archive.org/details/rewardsfairies00kipl)

Answer (score 1):

Your passage is taken from Kipling's short story *The Wrong Thing* in a collection of stories entitled [Rewards and Faries](http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/RewardsFaries/wrongthing.html).

The first line of the story states

> Dan had gone in for building model boats

Your passage describes Dan working on one of his models, where the boat is held in a vice

[image: here]

The [counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_nautical_terms#Counter) of the boat is

> The part of the stern above the waterline that extends beyond the rudder stock culminating in a small transom. A long counter increases the waterline length when the boat is heeled, so increasing hull speed.

[image: here]


So what Dan is doing is repositioning his model boat to be able to work on the back portion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your  detailed instruction. I visually understand  what Dan was doing!!